# Python list of lists shrinks when flattened

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of xml file names, but they themselves are in lists too ([["xml name"], ...]).
Now, since each sublist contains only 1 string, I want to make them into the larger list's elements. However, when I do this, the length of the list shortens by 16 elements.
Since there are around 20.000 elements in total, checking and figuring out which elements are gone is highly impractical.

I tried list comprehension `xml_list = [element for sublist in xml_list for element in sublist]` at first, and it seemed to have caused the shrinkage.

I went on to try nesting with an option to append None, if the problem was due to empty values:

```
new_xml_list = []
for sublist in xml_list:
    for element in sublist:
        if element:
            new_xml_list.append(element)
        else:
            new_xml_list.append(None)
```

This seems to be producing the same list 16 elements short of the original.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: so what did you want to ask?

Comment: Some of `sublist` entries are probably empty (can't tell you why). You are only checking-and-replacing-with-None for `element`, not `sublist`.

Comment: @Psytho my desired outcome is a flattened list with the same number of elements as the original, so I wanted to know if there is a solution to this shrinkage problem

Comment: @Megalng That was it, thank you! Got confused by the element and sublist differences

Comment: If that works for you, you could try something like ```if sublist: new_xml_list.extend(sublist) else: empty_sublists += 1 …``` in your `for sublist`-loop to return empty sublists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why the code is not working
when **sublist is empty**, **the inner loop (for element in sublist) does not execute**, and as a result, **no elements are added** to the flattened list for that particular sublist.

###### Solution

```
# sample input    
xml_list=[[],["xml_2"],[],["xml_1"]]

new_xml_list = []
for sublist in xml_list:
     if len(sublist)==0:  #check for empty sub list
         new_xml_list.append(None)
     else:
         new_xml_list.append(sublist[0]) 
print(new_xml_list)
```

###### Output:

> [None, 'xml_2', None, 'xml_1']